# DataGrid template edit

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid

I've created datagrid with combobox (reading data from DB), but need to fix some problems, maybe someone of you can help me ;)

First of all, I used grouping in dataGrid (group by name Wzór#), and everytime I want to add new element, it shows on the bottom:
http://i45.tinypic.com/2l8yarp.png[^]
Is it possible, to create something like "new group" with this only (the new one) item? For example like:
Wzór 1
Wzór1 niebieski 22 1 1 1
Wzór1 czerwony 23 1 1 1
Wzór 2
Wzór 2 czarny 55 1 1 1
Add new item
ComboBox ComBox ComboBox TextBox TextBox TextBox (which are exactly same as marked in picture). I mean somethink like that:
http://i45.tinypic.com/2s0ms90.png[^]

Second problem i found is that, when Im adding new item, and changing anything in ComboBox1,2 or 3 and then when im begining edit any textbox, all values from combobox dissapear - any way to fix it?

Here is source code (Actually its not very complicated, i have 3 methods with fill combobox1, combobox2 and combobox3 from database, then after button click im creating new Product item which im adding to list):

```
wzoryCount = wzoryCB.Items.Count;
            List<Produkt> Produkty = new List<Produkt>();
           // for (int i = 0; i < wzoryCount; i++)
            //{

                Produkt p = new Produkt { wzor = "", kolor = "", cena = 0, rozmiar = "", indeks = "", kod = "" };
                Produkty.Add(p);
           // }

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Produkty;
            ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(Produkty);
            collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("wzor"));
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = collection;
```

I guess, i need to do something in beginEdit method for datagrid, but when i put there messagebox, it doesnt appear when im changing anything in combobox, but do when im changing textbox.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need ObservableCollection, not List.
Second you can do it in xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Produkty}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="wzor">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding wzor}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="kolor">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding kolor}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="cena">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding cena}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="rozmiar">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding rozmiar}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="indeks">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding indeks}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="kod">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding kod}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Ok, ill try with Collection, but second unfortunately doesnt work for me. I have exactly that code before:

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment, so ill post it here. This is code im using in xaml, so Your answed doesnt work i guess

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Wzór" Binding="{Binding Path=wzor}"  ></DataGridTextColumn>-->

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Wzór">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource wzoryList}" SelectedItem="{Binding wzor}"></ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>



        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Kolor">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource koloryList}" SelectedItem="{Binding kolor}"></ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rozmiar">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource rozmiarList}" SelectedItem="{Binding rozmiar}"></ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Indeks" Binding="{Binding Path=indeks}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kod" Binding="{Binding Path=kod}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cena" Binding="{Binding Path=cena}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
```